# Gear systems' efficiency comparison

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, bearings, energy-efficiency

For a given system, that requires a shaft-gear(n)-shaft connection, which system's configuration would be the most efficient to use (in terms of total energy loss minimization). Where gear(n) is n number of gears in between the shafts. Assume (crucial) that each gear is mounted on the ball bearings, the gears are helical and have same width. The gear material density is 2648kg/m<sup>3</sup>.

[For a visualization, here is how the two instances of the gear systems, which would need to be compared would look like.](https://geargenerator.com/beta/#xUu3ob6CLb6CLb6CDRhtTS$uaDbazodjnToBrvCD2kGY576assId9ZvhEtf6n7zWBgoUpQbftMyMs@sqyYeMhJGX5e@j6M3sgb07JZcAaN2HF1OIfPc8aSxq0CTFETw26PWgA5hkUntbum5wUB2eZzaILn05TALAfPa0Ls@ul3W3sttkupTDmEf2UNu46me@gBbBJz16anAcF2UW)

I have been poking around this problem for quite a while now, using the simple approximations (like assuming the bearing contact energy loss to be around 0.99 and the gear mesh contact energy loss to be around 0.98-0.99), while also trying to apply the more detailed and in depth calculations (like
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241703345_Power_Loss_Prediction_in_High-Speed_Roller_Bearings
and
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/269575059_Determining_Power_Losses_in_the_Helical_Gear_Mesh_case_study).

However, I have been having trouble to wrap my head around the proper method of evaluation and how I should go about it. The simulation of a few systems might provide the best result, but I am not familiar with gear simulation software. I would really appreciate it, if somebody would point me in the right direction, as applying simple weight factors to the bearing efficiency does not sound like an appropriate approximation.